# Changing YouTube Resolution Using a Custom Player

Tags: javascript, youtube, video-player

Hi I use a system where the devs use the Youtube Live stream to air the live content on their platform. They just do the live stream video over Youtube then embed the youtube nocookie player.

The problem that we as the consumers facing on the platform is that when the nocookie player is used link example here https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/videouniqueIDgoeshere?controls=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&loop=0&fs=0&hl=en&enablejsapi=1

We can't control the quality of the video and hence we are forced to watch the live stream at the highest quality. Isn't there a way that we can just ( for the devs of the platform) add a quality change button as we find in the native player.

I know that I can just use the inspect element to hover to the actual video but please understand that I don't want to that everytime I start watching a stream. FYI the organisation uses a custom player over the embed on their website that just can change the playback speed

Comment: The quality button isn't there due to `controls=0`

Comment: As a "customer" there isn't anything you can do about it anyway. The website owner / manager needs to change it. If you want to fix it for yourself, install browser addons like Tampermonkey / Greasemonkey. It allows you to inject your own Javascript code into any website you visit and have it apply changes for you so you don't have to do it over and over again.